# using dhcp but IP is xx.xx.xx.0

Tags: python, sockets, networking, operating-system, ip

I am a newbie in fedora , and met this awful problem from I erase my `/etc/sysconfig/ifcfg-enp0s25` by mistake.

And then my ip became an external ip xxx.xx.6.168.

To solve my ip to be an internal ip , I tried to rebuild the file by using `# vi ifcfg-enp0s25` and insert:

```
DEVICE=enp0s25
NAME=enp0s25
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
```

then `# service network restart`

and my IP became:10.xx.xx.0

This IP could connect internal network successfully but get wrong to get own socket:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "ldtp/__init__.py", line 593, in <module>
  _populateNamespace(globals())
File "ldtp/__init__.py", line 247, in _populateNamespace
  for method in client._client.system.listMethods():
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1243, in __call__
  return self.__send(self.__name, args)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1602, in __request
  verbose=self.__verbose
File "ldtp/client.py", line 146, in request
  self.send_content(h, request_body)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1459, in send_content
  connection.endheaders(request_body)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1053, in endheaders
  self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 897, in _send_output
  self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 859, in send
  self.connect()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 836, in connect
  self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
  raise err
socket.error: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

So how can I return to my past IP ??

Any advice is helpful!

Comment: You may want to also post this question [Superuser](http://superuser.com/), where the focus is on OS administration.

Comment: @jesper_bk thank for your advice , I post it now!

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be quite more informations in that file, check [this page](https://dingyichen.wordpress.com/2014/08/06/fedora-and-rhel-configure-static-ip-and-disable-networkmanager/) for further details. Hope this helps

Edit: since you can't visit the page i copied for you the example of that file, maybe here you will find some of the options you miss... maybe you had a static IP

```
HWADDR=REPLACE:WITH:YOUR:MAC:ADDRESS:HERE
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR0=REPLACE.YOUR.IP.ADDRESS
PREFIX0=23
GATEWAY0=REPLACE.YOUR.GATEWAY.IP
DNS0=REPLACE.YOUR.DNS.IP
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_PRIVACY=no
NAME=enp0s25
ONBOOT=yes
DOMAIN="REPLACE.YOUR.DOMAIN"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
```

Comment: Sorry I can't open this website : (

Comment: I copied you the file example that was in that page ;-)

Comment: thanks ! And , in fact , I can't remember my old IP and old Gateway.....Is any ip in the network segment will be okay to write in this file?

Comment: About gateways... usually they are the first or last number of your ip network... for example XX.XX.XX.1 or XX.XX.XX.254... but it depends on the structure of your network... you should really ask to someone already connected to that network or to the sysadmin